# I cannot install node module 'node-sass' with yarn@1.22.10

Tags: vuejs2, npm-install, node-sass

I'm writing a vue 2 project with element-ui, I need to install `node-sass` module but no matter which version I install, they all failed. My computer is running macOS 11.4, how can I install node-sass successfully? `webpack` version is 4.46.0.

```sh
% yarn add node-sass@4

...

1 error generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/xxx/Workspace/web/h5/vue-demo/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:394:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 20.6.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/16.4.0/bin/node" "/Users/xxx/Workspace/web/h5/vue-demo/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/vorbote/Workspace/web/h5/vue-demo/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v16.4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete package-lock.json and run npm install again

Answer (score 0):

node-sass v4 does not support Node 16 https://github.com/sass/node-sass#node-version-support-policy